# Method for getting items from collection with specific key, value pair and also remove it from original collection in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

i was finding method for **fetching item in collection by specific key and value**, and i have found one which is [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where),

But i also **want to delete that item after fetching it from original collection**, but i couldn't find any method which can do both.

i have seen `pull()` method but it fetches by key and removes that column from collection but i want to remove particular item only.

I have looked in [collection doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections), but couldn't find any native method so i am using 2 method to achieve that need, the code is as below:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100],
]);

$filtered_items = $collection->where('price', 100);

$filtered_collection = $collection->whereNotIn('price', [100]);
```

i am thinking that above 2 method will be little overhead if i can accomplish it in one method, so i am looking for other solutions guys, thanks beforehand your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this one https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-partition

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100],
]);

$filtered_items = $collection->where('price', 100);

list($neededCollection, $filteredCollection) = $collection->partition(function ($i) {
    return $i['price'] == 100;
});

dd($neededCollection, $filteredCollection);
```

result like this 
[image]

Comment: your method works ok, but i was looking for inbuilt method but i think there is not available any method like that, so thanks.